# How to exclude taint nodes from outputs in kubectl get nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I try to check **how many** nodes are **ready** (not including nodes tainted **NoSchedule**) and write **the number** to text file **output.txt**.

Could you give me any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `kubectl get nodes` doesn't show taints, so you can't just filter with `grep`. In that case you can set the output as json and use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (or yaml and use [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)) to process it:

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -c '.items[].spec.taints' | grep -v NoSchedule | wc -l > output.txt
```

`-c` option in `jq` is to output each element in a single line, instead of pretty printing it, in case you have multiple taints. The rest has already been explained in [Abdennour TOUMI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921626/how-to-exclude-taint-nodes-from-outputs-in-kubectl-get-nodes/62921857#62921857)

Answer (score 2):

```
kubectl get nodes | grep Ready | grep -v NotReady | grep -v NoSchedule \
  | wc -l  > output.txt
```

This single command will do the job for you:

> Notes:
>
> - While `grep` includes lines, `grep -v` excludes lines
> - `wc -l` counts the number of lines.
> - number of output's lines is the same number of nodes with criteria you described

Answer (score 2):

Full proof Query to get nodes except node has taint effect NoSchedule on it

```
kubectl get node -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.taints[*].effect}{"\n"}{end}' | grep -v NoSchedule | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command can be used without jq or where jq is not installed.

```
kubectl get nodes --selector='!node-role.kubernetes.io/master' --no-headers | grep -v SchedulingDisabled | wc -l > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
kubectl describe nodes | grep -i taint | grep -v NoSchedule | wc -l
```